# Need help on refreshing the JWT token on PostMan

Tags: sharepoint-online, office365api, jwt, sharepoint-rest-api

I just created an App today and now it got successfully working but all of sudden i am getting a message saying that "Invalid JWT token. The token is expired".

What should i do refresh this token.

I created an app using Sharepoint Online app creation by following below blog: https://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/

Answer (score 0):

If an app is generated today and you have also generated to the ClientID and Client Secret today too. I am not sure why it has been expired.

What you can do is you can create a new client secret key using steps as provided in a link below:
http://trickycoder.com/renew-an-expiring-client-secret-in-a-sharepoint-provider-hosted-apps-add-in-without-deploying-the-apps-again-by-changing-client-secret-key-using-powershell/

MSDN link: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/replace-an-expiring-client-secret-in-a-sharepoint-add-in

Let me if this helps